# Using isinstance for a list of bools / ints

Tags: python, isinstance

I have a list of ints,

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
```

how do I do a `isinstance` on this, to return `True` only for a list of ints?

```
isinstance(lst, list[int]) # does not work
```

Comment: yes, that would always be a possibility, to do a separate check for ints, but I was looking for a way to have a list of int check with isinstance, and further use it with match-case

Comment: No, such a thing does not exist within the runtime of Python, though at the type checker at the type hinting level it may work, e.g. `lst: list[int] = [1, 2, 3]`. Does not apply at runtime, however.

Answer (score 3):

Try using all in conjunction with isinstance, like this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

result = all(isinstance(x, int) for x in lst)

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Perhaps maybe a class can be used in this case**

This is probably the closest way to check within the `isinstance` function itself.

I tried implementing a similar logic of the `sorted` function, where `sorted(x, key=lambda x:x[0])`

```
class integer_valid:

    def __init__(self, tuple):

        """ Valid integer tuple """

def validator(int_tup):

    all_ints = True

    for element in int_tup:
        if not isinstance(element, int):
            all_ints = False

    if all_ints:
        int_tup = integer_valid(int_tup)

    return int_tup
```

**Outputs**

```
int_tup_1 = (1,2,3)

print (isinstance(validator(int_tup_1), integer_valid)) # prints True

int_tup_2 = (1,'2',3)

print (isinstance(validator(int_tup_2), integer_valid)) # prints False
```

A single liner can also be used:

```
result = isinstance(
            integer_valid(int_tup) if all(isinstance(element, int)
            for element in int_tup) else int_tup,
        integer_valid)
```

Comment: Suggested: `True if isinstance(element, int) else False` => `isinstance(element, int)`

Comment: Nice catch! I haven't got a clue why I wrote that, probably cuz of 4 in the morning.

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap that in a list comprehension. You can just pass a generator expression to `all`, which is more efficient.

Comment: True, changed that.